# Create a Grid Layout Dynamically and manage it in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, grid, qml, qgridlayout

I'm new in Qt and currently I'm having some trouble. I want to create a grid layout in Qt from the c++ code and to be able to manage it from there. I have tried many different things but none of them work.

Basically, what I want to do is to have a window with a button in it(done that), and by pressing the button the window should change into a grid of buttons with no fixed number of rows or columns. ( hope I was clear on what I want to do)

At this point, I have created two .qml , one qml file has the code for the first window(the one with the one and only button) and the other qml file has a grid layout with nothing in it. There are also two c++ files the first one is the main.cpp and on the second one is the code I am writing to "fill" the grid on the click of the button.

Again, I'm new to Qt so if you have any better ideas please let me know!

Comment: It would be great if you will add some code instead of describing what you did. Anyway, what a sense to create and manage QML object from C++? It's quite simple to do that with QM only.

Comment: @folibis And how will I create the grid with  an unknown number of dimensions and multiple buttons in each cell?

Comment: You have to clarify this point. What does it mean - unknown number of dimensions?

Comment: @folibis I mean that the number dimensions will be randomly generated every time this window is created , which means that the number of buttons  is not static either(dimensionX*dimensionY). Basically, I want to create repeatedly buttons  in the qml file. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: You use a `Repeater { model: Math.round(Math.random() *  2147483647); delegate: Button {} }`

Comment: Wow ... @derM be carefully with such examples -)

Comment: @derM A repeater is what I ended up using however it seems that I can;t get over variable binding problems when I set the position of each button(I use counters for x and y coordinates. I t seems that in the end ALL the buttons end up in the same cell)

Comment: You can't use x and y coordinates, when you want to use a grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Repeater` to create some amount of `Button`s as children of the `Grid`. The `Grid` will automatically set the positions of the `Button`s so you should not set any `anchors` or coordinates.

To handle the signals, you define one signal somewhere, that you then connect to the buttons signal.

```
Grid {
    id: buttonGrid
    signal buttonClicked(int index)
    Repeater {
        model: 100 // or any integer number
        delegate: Button {
            onClicked: buttonGrid.buttonClicked(index)
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of using a integer model, you might also use e.g a `ListModel` or any `QAbstractItemModel`-descendent. Then you can also use their roles, to get stuff like textes or colors or functions...

A simple array with textes would also be possible.

Comment: Signal was  what I needed! Thanks!